# [AMPL]Impose a sum to be equal to the number of elements

Tags: numbers, element, ampl

I'm trying to impose a simple constrain that however doesn't work in any way I try. I'd to impose:

```
subject to myConstrain:
   sum { a1 in A, a2 in A }  myVar[a1,a2] = *<<<number of elements of the set A>>>*
```

How can I do that? Is there a function to use? I try in this way but it doesn't work.

```
subject to myConstrain:
   sum { a1 in A, a2 in A }  myVar[a1,a2] = sum {a in A} 1;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write such constraint as follows:

```
subject to myConstrain:
  sum{a1 in A, a2 in A} myVar[a1, a2] = card(A);
```